# Examples of order isomorphisms / similarities between well ordered sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory, well-orders

My set theory notes define a similarity (or order isomorphism) between two $\textbf{well-ordered}$ sets $(X,\leq_{1})$ and $(Y,\leq_{2})$ as a bijection $f:X\longrightarrow Y$ such that $x_1 \leq_1 x_2 \iff f(x_1) \leq_2 f(x_2)$. Now I do not have any explicit examples of these and I am struggling to think of any, as the definition specifies well-ordered sets as opposed to posets.

I tried showing that the function $f:\mathbb{Z}\longrightarrow \mathbb{N}, f(z)=2z  (z>0), f(z)=1-2z (z\leq 0)$ was one, and it turns out its not an order isomorphism, but I forgot that under that usual ordering of $\mathbb{Z}$, it is not a well-ordering.

So, can anyone give a simple example of what I'm looking for?

Thanks

Comment: Given any two well ordered sets $X$ and $Y$ either they are isomorphic, or one embeds into the other as an initial segment, so there are plenty of examples, just pick your favourite distinct well ordered sets!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be having a hard time coming up with suitable examples of well-ordered sets. Here’s a simple concrete example to get you started.

Let $X=\Bbb N\times\{0,1\}$, and let $\preceq$ be the [lexicographic order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) on $X$: $\langle m,i\rangle\preceq\langle n,j\rangle$ iff $m<n$, or $m=n$ and $i\le j$. Thus, $\langle 0,0\rangle$ is the $\preceq$-least element of $X$, and the next few in increasing order are $\langle 0,1\rangle,\langle 1,0\rangle,\langle 1,1\rangle$, and $\langle 2,0\rangle$. It’s a straightforward exercise to verify that this is a well-order and that

$$f:X\to\Bbb N:\langle n,i\rangle\mapsto 2n+i$$

is an order-isomorphism whose inverse is

$$f^{-1}:\Bbb N\to X:n\mapsto\left\langle\left\lfloor\frac{n}2\right\rfloor,n-2\left\lfloor\frac{n}2\right\rfloor\right\rangle\;.$$

Comment: You may know about this, but an interesting example of a partially ordered set that is somewhat difficult to prove is linearly/totally ordered, and extremely difficult to prove is well ordered, was given in [*An ordered set of arithmetic functions representing the least* $\varepsilon$-*number* by Thoralf Skolem (1957)](https://www.google.com/search?q=Skolem+%22ordered+set+of+arithmetic+functions%22+Ehrenfeucht).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro: Thanks; I don’t think that I had seen that before.

Comment: Ah, this is a brilliant example! Thank you very much.

Comment: @Natasha: You’re very welcome.

Comment: @brian M. Scott the inverse function seems to not work for  $(2,1)$ ?

Comment: @Thehomeschooler: $\langle 2,1\rangle$ isn’t in the domain of $f^{-1}$, so I don’t know what you mean.

Comment: @brian M. Scott isn't the function bijective though I don't understand how $(2,1)$   cannot be included in the domain since it is in the cartesian product of $ \mathbb{N}   \times   \{0,1\}$

Comment: @Thehomeschooler: The domain of $f^{-1}$ is $\Bbb N$. (To get $\times$ use `\times`.)

Comment: Yes but since $f(2,1)$=5  shouldn't the inverse of $5 =(2,1)$

Comment: @Thehomeschooler: $f^{-1}(5)$ **is** $\langle 2,1\rangle$. $\left\lfloor\frac{5}2\right\rfloor=2$, and $5-2\left\lfloor\frac{5}2\right\rfloor=5-2\cdot2=5-4=1$.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott i understand know thanks as usual for the help

Comment: @Thehomeschooler: You’re welcome.